# pickle.dumps compatibility in python2,3

Tags: python, pickle, hashlib

I am trying to write a function to md5 hash any python object. And I want in python2 and python3 it returns me the same md5 value.

I know pickle.dumps in python3, it returns bytes, and in python2, it returns str. As you can see the following code gives me the same string now:

```
print( [      pickle.dumps( obj, protocol = 2 )   ] ) # in python2
print( [ str( pickle.dumps( obj, protocol = 2 ) ) ] ) # in python3
```

both gives me:

```
['\x80\x02]q\x00(U\x011q\x01K\x02U\x013q\x02K\x04e.']
```

But the problem is that, in python3:

```
hashlib.md5.update( some_string )
```

have to be encoded. If I encode the string in python3, then it won't give me the same md5 value as in python2. Who can give me a solution? Thank you guys.

here's my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import hashlib
import pickle
import sys

is_py2 = (sys.version_info[0] == 2)

obj = ['1',2,'3',4]
m = hashlib.md5()

if is_py2:                                                    # if it's python2
    print(    [      pickle.dumps( obj, protocol = 2 ) ] )
    m.update(        pickle.dumps( obj, protocol = 2 )   )
else:                                                         # if it's python3
    print(    [ str( pickle.dumps( obj, protocol = 2 ) ) ] )
    m.update(        pickle.dumps( obj, protocol = 2 ).encode( "utf-8" ) ) # I wish I could don not encode

print( m.hexdigest() )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a one liner to do 2x and 3x encoding, and you can do it for any encoding.

```
>>> hashlib.new(algorithm, repr(object).encode()).hexdigest()
```

See: https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto/blob/master/klepto/crypto.py#L26 for the full context of the variable names… and see the rest of the file for many more abstractions on encoding, serialization, and the like. All work in python 2.x and 3.x.

I see you want python 2.x and 3.x to return the same hash.  Hmm... I don't think that works.  If it has any chance or returning the same `md5` encoding in 2.x as it does in 3.x, you might have to hit it with `repr` or `pickle` (protocol 2) or something else first.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import klepto
>>> klepto.crypto.hash(klepto.crypto.pickle(object), algorithm='md5')
'ee16782749cb00e4b66922df545877f0'
```

So, pickle and `md5` doesn't seem to work, and generally shouldn't because some objects have changed between 2.x and 3.x (for example `object` was a `type` now it's a `class`). That also means `repr` or other things like that won't work as an encoder in general either.

```
Python 3.3.5 (default, Mar 10 2014, 21:37:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import klepto
>>> klepto.crypto.hash(klepto.crypto.pickle(object), algorithm='md5')
'35eb4c374cafe09c8ac01661701b6b6e'
```

Maybe there's one of `klepto`'s other encoders that would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

1) `pickle.dumps` will return a byte string, so your print is wrong.

2) If by some reason you have such content on a unicode string, you cannot use a multi byte codec as utf-8 (the default).

```
foo = '\x80\x02]q\x00(U\x011q\x01K\x02U\x013q\x02K\x04e.'.encode('latin-1')
```

`latin-1` will have a 1 to 1 mapping so you'll end up with the correct bytes.

---

PS: Why are you using a list inside print? Maybe you're looking for `print(repr(...))`

Comment: Would you please give me the code to make md5 value of an object the same in both py2,3?